# how to click on a map and capture the location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps

I'm new to google maps API and need directions.

I want to let a user navigate a map (embedded in my page) and when she clicks, I want to capture the location and save it somehow.

I'm using rails 3 and have been looking for a gem or plugin, but only thing I found was YM4R/GM that's apparently using an old GM api and only works with rails 2...

If the answer is RTFM the Google-maps api v3, I apologize ;-)

Comment: yes, you should read the API, you have the answer to your question there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/) gathers a bunch a code samples related to Google API. Moreover, it provides a embedded IDE which allow to easily try out some code on the fly.

[This](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=libraries#event_arguments_v3) piece of code should help you in retrieving the clicked location.

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    alert(event.latLng.lat());
    alert(event.latLng.lng());
});
```